# Loop JQuery Function

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build an Image fade in and out system; the code I currently have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slider#1").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#1").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#2").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#2").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#3").delay(11000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#3").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#4").delay(16000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#4").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        });
```

How could I make it so that this automatically repeats once it ends?

Comment: New to the site? Take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) :)

Comment: well you are refering to a infinite bucle???mmmm it's not recommended that you have this in your app 'cause it will overflow your memory...why is that good for??what do you want to do???

Comment: Put the code in a function and call it after the last animation. You could even do this without adding a new function (I'll let you figure out how (tip: you need a reference to the function your code is currently in)). http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete

Comment: I want to just make the images loop for infinity.

Comment: When you say after the last animation, where do you mean?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete: *"complete: A function to call once the animation is complete."* and *"Callback Function: If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence."*

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `.promise()`'s `.done()` to listen when done and run again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    runShow();
    function runShow() {
        $(".slider#1").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#1").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#2").delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#2").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#3").delay(11000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#3").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $(".slider#4").delay(16000).fadeIn(2000);
        $(".slider#4").delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);
        $('.slider').promise().done( runShow );
    }
});
```

Note: You may have issues with your numeric `ID`'s; so consider using valid ones.

Answer (score -2):

```
var fadeTime = 1000,
    bannerDuration = 2000;
function rotateBanner() {
    var $current = $('.slider:visible');
    var $next = $current.next();
    if($next.length === 0) {
        $next = $('.slider:first');
    }
    $current.fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $next.fadeIn(fadeTime);
}
document.onload = function() {
    setInterval('rotateBanner()', bannerDuration);
};
```

Comment: somthing is wrong with stackoverflow formatting

Comment: Code without explanations is worthless. Please explain your answer.

Comment: *"somthing is wrong with stackoverflow formatting"* Use spaces instead of tabs.